# 'object' does not contain a definition for dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using below describe method. That return dynamic result.

```
public static dynamic GetCouponDetailsbyCouponID(Guid couponID)
        {
            using (var loEntities = new Entities())
            {
                dynamic nonWinnerGift = (from nw in loEntities.CorporateNonWinnerGift
                                         join um in loEntities.Users on nw.UserID equals um.Id
                                         where nw.IsDeleted != true && nw.CouponID == couponID
                                         select new
                                         {
                                             FullName = (um.FirstName + " " + um.LastName),
                                                 Title = nw.Title,
                                                 Description = nw.Description,
                                                 LogoName = nw.LogoName,
                                                 CouponID = nw.CouponID,
                                                 IsDiscount = nw.IsDiscount,
                                                 Discount = nw.Discount,
                                                 Desclaiemer = nw.Desclaiemer
                                             }).SingleOrDefault();    
                return nonWinnerGift;
            }
        }

 dynamic expandDoObject = new ExpandoObject();
```

When I am trying to access "couponData.LogoName" than thrown dynamic run-time exception. Please find below my exception
"A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in ClosetAuctions.dll
[image]Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'LogoName'"

```
                var couponData = CorporateNonWinnerGiftBL.GetCouponDetailsbyCouponID(couponID);

                if (couponData != null)
                {
                    string fileName = couponData.LogoName;
                }
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamically typed code to pass data around? This isn't javascript.

Comment: I have two classes and I want to return in combine both parameter by using linq query. And I don't want to create separate class. So Please suggest me what I need to do.

Comment: Return an aggregate class instead, for example. `class Result { public WinnerGift WinnerGift { get; set; } public User User { get; set; } }`

Comment: @decastro, Thanks for your quick response.
But, I don't want to create a new class. If I create a using new class by using both classes parameter that is easy, but my main concern is that don't want to new class.

Comment: So does `couponData` contain a property `LogoName`? tell us how you checked that.

Comment: You're returning an instance of an anonymous type. If you weren't using `dynamic`, your only choice here would be to return an `object` - the anonymous type is unknown outside of your own function. If you had a variable of type `object`, you'd get a compile time error that it doesn't have a `LogoName` property. All you've done with `dynamic` is defer *exactly the same lookup rules* until runtime. At runtime, the best type that can be determined is `object`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever why is that? At runtime the property should be found.

Comment: @VishalKiri If you don't want to do things the right way, then don't be surprised when your program starts crashing left and right.

Comment: @dcastro, Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"RuntimeBinderException" has already been answered on below articles please refer it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/30b916bf-7e59-4d8d-b7bc-076d4289a018/type-inference-turns-my-vars-to-dynamic?forum=csharplanguage

Try to below code:

```
public static dynamic GetCouponDetailsbyCouponID(Guid couponID)
{
    using (var loEntities = new Entities())
    {
        var nonWinnerGift = (from nw in loEntities.CorporateNonWinnerGift
            join um in loEntities.Users on nw.UserID equals um.Id
            where nw.IsDeleted != true && nw.CouponID == couponID
            select new
            {
                FullName = (um.FirstName + " " + um.LastName),
                Title = nw.Title,
                Description = nw.Description,
                LogoName = nw.LogoName,
                CouponID = nw.CouponID,
                IsDiscount = nw.IsDiscount,
                Discount = nw.Discount,
                Desclaiemer = nw.Desclaiemer

             }).SingleOrDefault();

        dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();

        d.FullName = nonWinnerGift.FullName;
        d.Title = nonWinnerGift.Title;
        d.Description = nonWinnerGift.Description;
        d.LogoName = nonWinnerGift.LogoName;
        d.CouponID = nonWinnerGift.CouponID;
        d.IsDiscount = nonWinnerGift.IsDiscount;
        d.Discount = nonWinnerGift.Discount;
        d.Desclaiemer = nonWinnerGift.Desclaiemer;

        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: A Plus for actually reading the question and code! lol Great answer!

Comment: interesting interesting, so I should never forget not to use anonymous types out of it's scope, though it's my dream

Answer (score 13):

It is not advisable to use dynamic object in your use case. But this is my opinion.

Anyway, to access member of dynamic object,

```
string fileName = couponData.GetType().GetProperty("LogoName").GetValue(couponData, null);
```

Comment: Can you please explain me about "d"? **GetValue(d, null)**

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I really very appreciate and it is working.

Comment: Thanks you for Answer, it is good and easy to use for return list <a'> :)