# Unable to display LINQ query output values from controller to view

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Track(string awb)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Track Your Shipment";
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
        ViewBag.ShipmentNo = awb;
        FLCourierDetail trackOutput = new FLCourierDetail();

        if (awb != null)
        {
            trackOutput = db.FL_CourierDetail.SingleOrDefault(fLCourierDetail => fLCourierDetail.AWBNumber == awb);
            if (trackOutput != null)
            {
                var courierId = db.FL_CourierDetail.Where(s => s.AWBNumber == awb).Select(s => s.Courier);
                var currentStatus = (from c in db.FL_CourierDetail
                                     join s in db.FL_CourierStatus
                                     on c.Courier equals s.CourierId
                                     where c.AWBNumber == awb
                                     select new { awb = c.AWBNumber, staus = s.StatusId, updated = s.StatusId, remark = s.Remark }).ToList();
                ViewBag.CurrentStatus = currentStatus;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Shipment number not found.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Please provide valid Shipment number.";
        }

        return View(trackOutput);
    }
```

#### View

```
       <div class="col-md-6">
            @{ 
                var status = ViewBag.CurrentStatus;

                foreach (var item in status)
                {
                    <p>@item</p>
                }
            }
        </div>
```

If I iterate using foreach or if loop I am able to see the data in debug, but I am not able to write in html.

#### Debug

[image]

#### Web Page

[image]

#### Error

I am not able to read each value like awb, status, date etc.

[image]

Did I miss anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query result is an anonymous class, within the loop, each item is an object and thus the exception, object has now `awb` property.

One way to solve this is by defining a class:

```
public class Status {
    public string awb { get; set; }
    public int staus { get; set; }
    public int updated { get; set; }
    public string remark { get; set; }
}
```

Then your select would look like:

```
... select new Status { awb = c.AWBNumber, staus = s.StatusId, updated = s.StatusId, remark = s.Remark }).ToList();
```

Then, within the View:

```
var status = (List<Status>) ViewBag.CurrentStatus;
```

Another possible solution is to use [strongly typed view model](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=strongly%20typed%20view%20model%20in%20mvc&oq=strongly%20typed%20view%20model%20mv&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4790j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you could create a Model class for returned data;

```
var currentStatus = (from c in db.FL_CourierDetail
    join s in db.FL_CourierStatus
        on c.Courier equals s.CourierId
    where c.AWBNumber == awb
    select new CurrentStatus  { awb = c.AWBNumber, staus = s.StatusId, updated = s.StatusId, remark = s.Remark }).ToList();

public class CurrentStatus
{
    public string awb { get; set; }

    public int staus { get; set; }

    public int updated { get; set; }

    public string remark { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, you can't get output an entire object, you should specify properties which you want to display;

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            @{ 
                var status = (List<CurrentStatus>) ViewBag.CurrentStatus;

                foreach (var item in status)
                {
                    <p>@item.awb</p>
                    <p>@item.staus</p>
                    <p>@item.updated</p>
                    <p>@item.remark</p>

                }
            }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really strange, but in console application the following code **actually works**:

```
dynamic even = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
              .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
              .Select((x, index) => new { Position = index, Num = x });

// Output:
// Position: 0, Number: 2
// Position: 1, Number: 4
foreach (dynamic item in even)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Position: {item.Position}, Number: {item.Num}");
}
```

However, in ASP.NET ths doesn't work, and I don't really understand because `ViewBag` *is* dynamic, too.

**UPDATE**

Same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348507/object-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-dynamic). A quote from there:

> You're returning an **instance** of an anonymous type. If you weren't using `dynamic`, your only choice here would be to return an `object` - the anonymous type is unknown outside of your own function. If you had a variable of type `object`, you'd get a compile time error that it doesn't have a `LogoName` property. All you've done with `dynamic` is defer *exactly the same lookup rules* until runtime. At runtime, the best type that can be determined is `object`.

As this answer states, the following *must not* work, but it *works*:

```
static void DoWork()
{
    dynamic evens = GetEvens();
    foreach (dynamic item in evens)
        Console.WriteLine($"Position: {item.Position}, Number: {item.Num}");

}

static dynamic GetEvens() =>
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
    .Select((x, index) => new { Position = index, Num = x });
```

In this case I return dynamic. However, the code work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion bro :)