# Query Display Error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm getting an error while mounting and displaying this query.

```
var itens = _context.ContasReceber
  .Include(x => x.Pessoas)
  .Include(x => x.PlanosServicos)
  .Select(c => new
  {
     Identificador = c.Pessoas.NIdentificador,
     NomePessoa = c.Pessoas.Nome,
     c.Observacao,
     c.Vencimento,
     c.Valor,
     c.Quitado,
     c.DataPagamento,
     c.ValorPago
    })
    .ToList();
    ViewData["Contas"] = itens;
```

cshtml:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Contas)
 {
    <tr>
      <th>
          @item.Identificador              
      </th>
       <th>
          @item.NomePessoa
       </th>
       <th>
          @item.Observacao
        </th>
        <th>
          @item.Vencimento
        </th>
        <th>
          @item.Quitado
        </th>
         <th>
          @item.DataPagamento
         </th>
         <th>
            @item.ValorPago
         </th>
     </tr>
}
```

The error is:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Identificador'
CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , object )

Comment: You are running into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348507/object-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-dynamic) issue. A common solution is to create a "ViewModel" that has the properties you want to work with in that particular view and project your entity properties into it. AutoMapper is great for this.

Answer (score 1):

In razor pages PageModel, you could use ViewModel to return custom data.
Here is a simplified version of the demo.

In cshtml.cs:

```
 public class ContasViewModel
    {
        public string Identificador { get; set; }
        public string NomePessoa { get; set; }
        public string Observacao { get; set; }
    }

    public IList<ContasViewModel> Contas { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {

        Contas = await _context.ContasReceber
          .Include(x => x.Pessoas)
          .Include(x => x.PlanosServicos)
          .Select(c => new ContasViewModel
          {
              Identificador = c.Pessoas.NIdentificador,
              NomePessoa = c.Pessoas.Nome,
              Observacao= c.Observacao

          }).ToListAsync();

    }
```

In cshtml:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Contas)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>
                @item.Identificador
            </th>
            <th>
                @item.NomePessoa
            </th>
            <th>
                @item.Observacao
            </th>

        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over your items `foreach (var item in ViewBag.Contas)`, the type of `item` is `Object`. Object has no properties by default. Since you are using an anonymous type, you can change your foreach to `foreach (dynamic item in ViewBag.Contas)` which will allow you to reference its properties as it will treat `item` as a dynamic object similar to ViewBag.

Comment: Continuous receiving the same error: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Identificador'
CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , object )

Comment: Actually it's not a controller, it's a "PageModel" from asp.net razor. In this case
  the "ViewBag" elento is not recognized.